# PHP pages with MYSQL database not showing in browser

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I tried to insert data (using the behavior tab) into database in Dreamweaver. I had connected the database too. However, it didn't work as the page can't be displayed in the live version nor the browser.

I also can't retrieve all the data in the table, but if I only choose to display one column and one row it shows up. I am not quite sure what's the problem and I've been stuck for days trying to find the solution. The message shown is "An unknown error occurred while discovering dynamically-related files" and when I press live it says "The connection with the server was reset".

Perhaps somebody could give me ideas what's the problem? I think it probably has something to do with the database since my html and other PHP pages could be shown in the browser. I think I did the right setting for testing sites and servers and I am using WAMP server.

Now here's the code. I don't really write any, I just used the Insert>Data Object>Insert Record.

```
<?php virtual('CAT400/Connections/connectDB.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO company (`Company Registration No`, `Company Name`, `Contact No`, Address) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Company_Registration_No'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Company_Name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Contact_No'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connectDB, $connectDB);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $connectDB) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "/CAT400/Certificate Registration.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Company Registration No:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Company_Registration_No" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Company Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Company_Name" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Contact No:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Contact_No" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Address:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Address" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

This is what's written.

Comment: Paste your relevant code here and I'm sure someone will be glad to help.

Comment: Could you tell us what commands are you using to fetch sql query and get the data? It seems something should be wrong in the code

Comment: Could you post some of your code @nf91?

Comment: I already added codes.

Comment: have u turn on your error reporting display . to see errors?

Comment: Hm From here i can't see geting data from database. Here you have only inserts. What error you get?

Comment: oops I didnt insert the whole code. But I already figured the solutions. I will edit it shortly.

Comment: Apparently the problem lies in the first line of my code. My friend pointed out the "<?php virtual('CAT400/Connections/connectDB.php'); ?>" line is weird and he ask me to changed it to "<?php include('Connections/connectDB.php'); ?>" and the problem is solved! I can insert data now to my database. I feel so silly. Thank you to everyone responding here!